# Buttons look messy in Android Studio when I run the application on Tablet

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to design 4 rows and 3 column of same size buttons. It does look fine in Android Studio when I click on "Infer Constraints" - But when I run it on my tablet it looks messy! What did I do wrong?
I've added xml code for 6 buttons (not the whole 12 because it's too long).

I expected the output to look like this:
[image: capture from Android Studio]

but the actual output is buttons which are not the same size and order
  [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MemoryGame"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/muses_spinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/connect_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button0_0"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="124dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1_0"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button1_2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1_0"
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button1_1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button0_0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button0_1"
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:text="BUTTON"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1_1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button0_2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button0_0"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1_1"
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button1_2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1_0"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button0_1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="103dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button1_1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button0_0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button0_2"
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1_2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1_1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/connect_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="302dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="302dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:text="connect"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/refresh_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="203dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="203dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:text="refresh"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/muses_spinner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/connect_button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/muses_spinner" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use another typ of layout. For example Linear Layout, Table Layout
P.S. i´m trying past some code but this f.. page not permited.

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxtHf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding in a grid layout in the Constraint layout. I have my column count set to 2, but in your case you just need to change it to 3

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Glossy_Grape"
tools:context=".ShopActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="650dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:translationY="80dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFireEgg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/fireegg_copy"
        android:contentDescription="@string/name"></ImageButton>
  </GridLayout>
```